expl3 create "function" that uses a list as its argument
consider calulating z(x,y)=2x+3y , and let x=5, y=6 , then how to define a function so that it can compute z(5,6) , and treat parameter {5,6} as a list by expl3?
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{ \foo }{m}
 {
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\foo{5,6} % returns 28

\end{document}


This is just a command with two arguments as-written, and with more than two the question doesn't really make any sense

that situation has been deleted .

Reading interface3 could save you some time…
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\fp_new_function:n { foo }
\fp_set_function:nnn { foo } { x,y } { 2*x+3*y }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\fpeval{foo(5,6)}

\end{document}

This prints 28.
A more general approach:
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\fp_new_function:n { genlin }
\fp_set_function:nnn { genlin } { a,b,x,y } { a*x+b*y }
\fp_new_function:n { foo }
\fp_set_function:nnn { foo } { x,y } { genlin(2,3,x,y) }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\fpeval{foo(5,6)}

\end{document}


\fpeval command is so powerful !

Like this?
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}{%
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } { #1 } 
  \fpeval{2*\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1}+3*\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {2}}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\foo{5,6} % returns 28

\end{document}


Yes . I found how to use \seq_item from your answer.

You have a tutorial (very good for me) here https://www.latex-project.org/news/2020/11/09/l3-tutorial/
